# Package name in .so file in android apk

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

Android can use .so file through JNI. The native function in C/C++ is bound to a Java function.

I want to use other developers' .so file (I don't have the source code). I know the interface of the native function, but I have faced some difficulties. It seems that the .so file is hard coded to bind for a certain package name.

Is there any way for me to use other developers' .so file?

If not, is it possible to decompile the .so file and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a package with the name that the shared object expects, in which you have a wrapper class whose only purpose is to load the library and provide the native methods to clients using this class.

Import that package into your own activity's package (or wherever you want to use it) and call the native methods through the wrapper class.

Comment: It works if the method is static, how about it is a object method?

Comment: Make those `public native` in the wrapper class rather than `public static native`. Or did you mean something else (if so, could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do and what errors you get)?

Comment: But the problem is that would the native method try to access the caller object or its'field in the C++ code? If yes, they can't access them in the wrapper class, right?

Comment: If the native code tries to make calls back to the Java object, then your wrapper class will have to implement the methods that the native code is trying to call. That is also true for static methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I only know the interface of the .so file but not the implementation. So I don't know what it would access...

Comment: @Michael: My application package is different than the package where I've kept the wrapper class for loading the libray. is that why `JNI_OnLoad` returning a bad version?